# More than one button with pending intent on notification with remoteView

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent, remoteview

I have a notification using a remoteView. On the notification I have 3 buttons, each of them with their own pendingIntent. For some reason only the last pendingIntent that I add with setOnClickPendingIntent works.

Here is some of the

```
    Intent intentPause = new Intent(context, BluetoothConnectionService.class);
    intentPause.putExtra("pause", device.device.getAddress());
    Intent intentIncrease = new Intent(context, BluetoothConnectionService.class);
    intentIncrease.putExtra("inc", device.device.getAddress());
    PendingIntent pendingIntentPause = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intentPause, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent pendingIntentIncrease = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intentIncrease, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    RemoteViews expandedView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_layout);

    expandedView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.noti_pause_heat_button, pendingIntentPause);
    expandedView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.noti_inc_heat_button, pendingIntentIncrease);



Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
        .setContentTitle(this.device.getName())
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.inu_small)
                        .setContentText("" + this.notificationId)
        .setContent(expandedView)
                    .build();
```

Answer (score 5):

use a different `requestCode` (second parameter of `getService`) for each `PendingIndent`. E.g.

```
PendingIntent pendingIntentPause = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intentPause, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
PendingIntent pendingIntentIncrease = PendingIntent.getService(context, 1, intentIncrease, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: Thank your sir! I don't know why your answer isn't been accepted